# Listen a ValueNotifier from class

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi im new in flutter and i have a class for notify changes of a global values in my app like this

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';


class GlobalNotifier {

  final counter = ValueNotifier<int?>(null);

  setValue(int value){
    counter.value = value;
  }

}
```

In another page i set the value with tap event executing this

```
var globalNotifier = GlobalNotifier();
globalNotifier.setValue(widget.item['id']);
```

I tested that the value is really changed and test the listener in the class GlobalNotifier its working fine but when i add a listener out of the class GlobalNotifier not notify nothing

```
var model = GlobalNotifier();
print('charged listeners');
model.counter.addListener(() {
  print('counter changed!');
  print(model.counter.value);
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var model = GlobalNotifier();

print('charged listeners');

model.counter.addListener(() {
    print('counter changed!');
    print(model.counter.value);
});

model.setValue(0 or [youvalue]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have 2 instances of `GlobalNotifier`:

- One called "globalNotifier"
- One called "model"

You need to make sure the instance of `GlobalNotifier` you're listening to is the same the same instance you're updating with setValue. You can accomplish this by creating a global instance of GlobalNotifier and using that everywhere:

```
 GlobalNotifier globalNotifier = GlobalNotifier();
```

Or, if you only need to access the notifier in a single widget, you can create a StatefulWidget and declare the GlobalNotifier in the State:

```
class Question68423299 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Question68423299({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Question68423299> createState() => _Question68423299State();
}

class _Question68423299State extends State<Question68423299> {
  GlobalNotifier globalNotifier = GlobalNotifier();

  @override
  void initState() {
    globalNotifier.counter.addListener(() {
      print('counter changed!');
      print(globalNotifier.counter.value);
    });
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('SO Question: 68423299'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            ValueListenableBuilder(
              valueListenable: globalNotifier.counter,
              builder: (context, value, child) {
                return Text('Value: $value');
              },
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  globalNotifier.setValue(globalNotifier.counter.value == null ? 0 : globalNotifier.counter.value! + 1);
                },
                child: const Text('Increment'))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

A full code example can be found [here](https://github.com/CodeOTR/stack_overflow) (replace the home widget with Question68423299.